# Application does not have the capability to make this API call on GRAPH API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, instagram

My issue is not about code, I'm tried to publish content on instagram.
So I use Graph API : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/getting-started
I followed steps :

First:

I set token in graph API

Then:

I make request to

> [GET] /me/accounts (get page id)
>
> [GET] /page_id?fields=instagram_business_account (get instagram page)
>
> [GET] /instagram_page/media (get media of instagram page)

Their steps work well but I'm not able to make this request

> [POST] /instagram_page/media?image_url=https://images.pexels.com/photos/248797/pexels-photo-248797.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500
>     &caption=#BronzFonz

I saw that : [Facebook Ads Insights API: (#3) Application does not have the capability to make this API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40142294/facebook-ads-insights-api-3-application-does-not-have-the-capability-to-make/49003374)

But he doesn't use Graph API

I use Graph API with autorizations

Can someone help me or tell me if he got the same result

Comment: Did you found the resolution?

Comment: Nope, I will try to become facebook and instagram parten to get more details

Comment: Hey @WyllisTM have you became a partner? I'm trying to use the API too

Comment: No, i'm going to become soon

Comment: Any updates? I am also facing the same issue!